# setBarSpacing not working in achartengine Android

Tags: android, eclipse, bar-chart, achartengine

I am trying to dar Bar Charts using `achartEngine`.  This is what I did till now.

```
public void drawBarChart()
    {

        setRenderer();
        chartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, getDataSet(), renderer, Type.STACKED);
        mainLayout.addView(chartView);
        chartView.repaint();

    }


    public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDataSet()
    {

         XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        XYSeries currentSeries = new XYSeries("Current Series Title");
        currentSeries.add(1, 10);
        currentSeries.add(2, 20);
        currentSeries.add(3, 15);
        currentSeries.add(4, 35);
        currentSeries.add(5, 25);
        dataset.addSeries(currentSeries);
        double maxY = currentSeries.getMaxY();
        renderer.setShowLegend(false);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(maxY*1.4);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(currentSeries.getMinX()-1);
        renderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{currentSeries.getMinX(),currentSeries.getMaxX()*1.4,currentSeries.getMinY(),currentSeries.getMaxY()*1.4});

        return dataset;
    }


    public void setRenderer()
    {
        renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();      
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(14);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(28);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(14);     
        renderer.setBarWidth(60);           
        renderer.setXLabelsAngle(-20);
        renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.RED);
        renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        renderer.setShowGridX(true);
        renderer.setGridColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        renderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[]{10,0,0,0});
        renderer.setAxesColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(14);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, Color.MAGENTA);
        renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "January");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "February");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "March");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "April");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "May");
        renderer.setXLabels(0); 
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.CYAN);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(26);

    }
```

But, I am not able to set the gap between bars.

I tried using `renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);` Even then its not showing any change. Did I make any mistake?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line -

```
renderer.setBarWidth(30);
```

when using this

```
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
```

I think we can use only one of these two setting at a time .

Comment: @keshav.. If I remove the `renderer.setBarWidth(30);` then its working fine. But, if I remove that then the bar width is too big. How to reduce that? Also, how to zoom out in the initial stage??

Comment: For reducing width, I think u have to adjust spacing, means set it to 0.8 or more.

Comment: And what about zoom u are asking I didn't get ?